# iOS How to achieve advert tracking e.g.:App(a) is installed owe to the app(b) advert

Tags: ios, idfa

I want to know how to achieve advert tracking e.g.:App(a) is installed owe to the app(b) advert. Any one can tell me,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conversion concept in ads. 
The different service providers all have a way to know how many clicked ads goal the installation.

Exemple with Google : https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/?hl=fr

Comment: Added a link  in the answer